# How to use ActiveRecord Query Cache with Custom SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, query-cache

In a stats part of a Rails app, I have some custom SQL calls that are called with ActiveRecord::Base.execute() from the model code. They return various aggregates.

Some of these (identical) queries are run in a loop in the controller, and it seems that they aren't cached by the ActiveRecord query cache.

Is there any way to cache custom SQL queries within a single request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if AR supports query caching for #execute, you might want to dig in the documentation.
Anyway, what you **can** do, is to use memoization, which means that you'll keep the results manually until the current request is over.

do something like this in your model:

```
def repeating_method_with_execute
   @rs ||= ActiveRecord::Base.execute(...)
end
```

This will basically run the query only on the first time and then save the response to `@rs` until the entire request is over.

If I am not wrong, Rails 2.x already has a macro named `memoization` on ActiveRecord that does all that automatically

hope it helps

Comment: I needed @@class_variables, but, other than that, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.